# Grouping Date/Time by hour in pivot table not working as expected

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, power-query

I have one Excel table appended to another (over 1.1 million rows so can't fit all of the data on one sheet) via a query in excel. I am using this append query as the source for a pivot table.

When I add the Date/Time field to the "Rows" section and group by hour, it is giving me these row labels:

[image: Row labels - as text]

When I group by hour on one of the sheets, I get this:

[image: Row labels - correct format]

The format of the rows column in the query is Date/Time. How do I get the Row Labels to display as times instead of this weird text?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using PowerPivot (Excel 2016). It allows you to format how each of the columns is displayed, so I entered the formula shown below:

[image: Powe Pivot Format]

Still not sure how you would do this without PowerPivot.